# Why are my generated randomly values are the same when I am put them in array?

Tags: java, arrays, random

Why are randomly generated values the same in the array?

When I am looking in the debug mode, I see that the values are the same in `ArrayList<String>`.

Can please anybody explain this?

```
public class CreateRandomSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> randomSet = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> storeData = new ArrayList<String>();
        String fileName = "file.txt";
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line = bf.readLine();
        String storeId;
        String storeName;
        String customer;
        String value;
        Random random = new Random();
        double randomValue;
        double start = 100;
        double end = 10000;
        while(line != null){
            storeData.clear();
            line = line.trim();
            CsvTokenizer csvTokenizer = new CsvTokenizer(line, ",");
            storeId = csvTokenizer.nextToken();
            if(csvTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
                storeName = csvTokenizer.nextToken();
                storeData.add(storeName);
            }
            if(csvTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
                value= csvTokenizer.nextToken();
                randomValue = end + (start * random.nextDouble()) ;
                storeData.add(String.valueOf(randomValue));
            }

            randomSet.put(storeId, storeData);
            line = bf.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just one `storeData` instance which you use as value for all the keys of your map. Therefore the values added to that `List` in the final iteration are the values you see for all the keys of your map.

You must create a new `List` in each iteration of your loop.

Change:

```
storeData.clear();
```

to:

```
storeData = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: But why `clear()` doesn't clear array at all ? I am expecting that my array will be empty after I used `clear()` method.

Comment: @Andrew Of course it clears the List. But all the values in your map refer to that same ArrayList object, so it clears all of them. And the values you add in the last iteration are not cleared.